# Steps to write better ActionBars in Android

Tags: android

These are my doubts while using ActionBar.

1) To make it prevalent across various tabs, I had to repeat the same code in all the tabs. Is there a better way to rewrite this part? I could have one ActionBar class which I can call everywhere, but that won't make it dynamic. (More options in certain tabs.)

2) I'm presently defining a menu and inflating it. Is it the best way to go about it? The problem I am facing here is I'm definitely not using the entire space and always running out of space to put in more actions. How to rectify it?

3) The third problem that I'm facing is a bug when I use Theme.Light. The app crashes. If I use Theme.Holo.Light, the app doesn't. Though, it still crashes in a 2.3 supporting phone. Anyway to rectify that? I mostly feel that I've missed out on backward compatibility or is Action bar not compatible with certain themes?

Comment: Sounds like some of this may be trying to support older versions of android, have you tried taking a look at ActionBarSherlock - http://actionbarsherlock.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers your 3rd question, straight from docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar is included in all activities that use the Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants), which is the default theme when either the targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or greater.

If you want to use ActionBar APIs, such as to add navigation modes and modify action bar styles, you should set the minSdkVersion to "11" or greater. If you want your app to support older versions of Android, there are ways to use a limited set of ActionBar APIs on devices that support API level 11 or higher, while still running on older versions. See the sidebox for information about remaining backward-compatible.

**Sidebox info**

If you want to provide an action bar in your application and remain compatible with versions of Android older than 3.0, you need to create the action bar in your activity's layout (because the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) class is not available on older versions).

To help you, the [Action Bar Compatibility](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) sample app provides an API layer and action bar layout that allows your app to use some of the ActionBar APIs and also support older versions of Android by replacing the traditional title bar with a custom action bar layout.